# How to send hidden SMS on android 6.0+

Tags: android

I'm currently building an S.O.S android app which gets the user location and sends a previously saved message with location included to a list of predefined users.

Is it possible to make the sent messages hidden to the default SMS app?

I need to leave no traces of sent messages because of the nature of my app. Some background: It will be used in case of kidnaps, domestic violence, etc. So as you can see the S.O.S messages need to be hidden from the attacker.

I'm using this function:

```
public void sendLocationSMS(String phoneNumber, String latitude, String longitude) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userMessage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String savedMsg = sharedPref.getString("userMessage", "");
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    StringBuffer smsBody = new StringBuffer(savedMsg);
    smsBody.append(" https://maps.google.com/maps?q=");
    smsBody.append(latitude);
    smsBody.append(",");
    smsBody.append(longitude);
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, smsBody.toString(), null, null);


}
```

Comment: I guess you should carefully study the APIs of the component you are using there then. Beyond that: maybe there is a way to *delete* SMSes from that SmsManager after having them send?

Comment: "Is it possible to make the sent messages hidden to the default SMS app?" - No. Not unless your app _is_ the default. Not for regular text messages.